# MariaDB SSL using self signed client cert with letsencrypt signed server cert

Tags: mysql, ssl, mariadb, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

How can I use self signed certs for encrypting client communications with MariaDB when the server side certificates are done via letsencrypt?

Most tutorials I've found, like https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-setup-mariadb-ssl-and-secure-connections-from-clients/, show you how to setup both server and client side certificates as self signed, sharing the same CA (Certificate Authority) certificate. This way works as expected, and when I connect to the DB via the command line it works with client side encryption.

***/etc/my.cnf:***

```
[mariadb]
ssl_cert=/certs/server-cert.pem
ssl_key=/certs/server-key.pem
ssl_ca=/certs/ca-cert.pem
```

***/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysql-clients.cnf:***

```
[mysql]
ssl-ca=/certs/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/certs/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=/certs/client-key.pem
```

With this configuration this command works:
`mysql -u root -p -h mysite.com --port=3310 --protocol=TCP --ssl-cert=/certs/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/certs/client-key.pem --ssl-ca=/certs/ca-cert.pem --ssl-verify-server-cert`

Note that I generated `ca-cert.pem` myself and used it to sign both the server and client certs, and that these certs verified correctly and after logging in and checking the servers status it indicates that SSL is being used.

This setup worked fine during development, but now my database is in production and I want to use letsencrypt certificates in my services. If I replace the server side certificates in my /etc/my.cnf file with the ones that letsencrypt gives me like so:

***/etc/my.cnf:***

```
[mariadb]
ssl_cert=/certs/cert.pem
ssl_key=/certs/privkey.pem
ssl_ca=/certs/chain.pem
```

but leave the 50-mysql-clients.cnf file with the self signed client certs as is, it no longer lets me log in using the certs. If i no longer try and use the client certs it still lets me log in using SSL, and a status check indicates that it is still using ssl, but the documentation says that this way the client packets aren't encrypted, only the servers.

Command that works: `mysql -u root -p -h mysite.com --port=3310 --protocol=TCP --ssl-verify-server-cert`

Command from before that no longer works: `mysql -u root -p -h mysite.com --port=3310 --protocol=TCP --ssl-cert=/certs/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/certs/client-key.pem --ssl-ca=/certs/ca-cert.pem --ssl-verify-server-cert`

Error Message: `ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Using the server certs letsencrypt generates in the command also doesn't work: `mysql -u root -p -h mysite.com --port=3310 --protocol=TCP --ssl-ca=/certs/chain.pem --ssl-cert=/certs/cert.pem --ssl-key=/certs/privkey.pem --ssl-verify-server-cert`

Error Message: `ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: unable to get issuer certificate`

***status check:***

```
MariaDB [(none)]> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.8-MariaDB, for osx10.15 (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:      4
Current database:
Current user:       root@myipaddress
SSL:            Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Current pager:      less
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server:         MariaDB
Server version:     10.5.4-MariaDB-1:10.5.4+maria~focal mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     mysite.com via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
TCP port:       3310
Uptime:         3 min 33 sec
```

How can I still do 2 way ssl encryption with both client and server when using letsencrypt certificates with MariaDB?

Comment: TLS connections are always encrypted, in both directions. Was user root created with `REQUIRE X509` or why do you specify a client certificate ?

Comment: I am specifying it because in the MaraDB documentation it says you must in order for the connection to be "2 way encrypted", see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/securing-connections-for-client-and-server/#enabling-tls-for-mariadb-clients, although now that I am reading the docs it looks like since i've loaded the client certs into an option file that it may already be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment..

1. One way TLS means, that the server sends his certificate to the client, and the client verifies it. Two way TLS means, that the client sends also his certificate to the server and the server verifies the client certificate.
   Latter one happens only, if the REQUIRE X509, REQUIRE SUBJECT, and/or REQUIRE ISSUER clauses are specified for the account. If no REQUIRE was specified, you don't have to specify a client certificate.
2. Regardless of one or two way a TLS connection always sends encrypted data in both directions (unless OpenSSL was built with NONE cipher support and client specified NONE cipher).
3. Error message: "unable to get local issuer certificate" means that something in the root certificate chain is missing.
   If it's not a self signed certificate, you should verify it with system ca (without specifying ssl-ca or ssl-ca-path) or add the server certificate to your ca file.

Comment: 1) & 2) okay good to know thanks for clarifying!
3) The server cert isn't self signed, but i believe these errors relate to the client cert which is. I'm not an expert on certs but i did run the `openssl verify -CAfile ca-cert.pem client-cert.pem` command after making them and the output said that everything was okay. How would i add the server cert to my ca file?

Comment: Again: Why do you need client cert? If your system ca doesn't work, combine the certs: `cat server-cert.pem client-cert.pem > ca-cert.pem` and use --ssl-ca=ca-cert.pem on client and server.

Comment: Can you combine certificates in this manner that aren't signed by the same CA? What if the certificates were made for different URLs? For instance my server-cert was made by letsencrypt for mysite.com, but my client-cert was self signed and could be for any URL (probably "MySite Admin", or "localhost" etc.)